# How do i get the list of items from array response

Tags: ionic-framework

I have this array and i need to get the skills into ion-badge.Please help

Here is what im trying but im getting undefined in console after assigning skills into the array containing skills.

```js
this.skills=this.iteminfo.skills;
 console.log(this.skills['name']);
```

---

```
{id: "10a6a311-a68c-47b0-97fc-013bf5da3375", status: 0, rating: 0, price: 600, schedule: "5/11/2019 9:00:00 AM", …}
client: {id: "ddc249f1-69c5-4418-85c9-4e0131724fb2", firstName: "Dan", lastName: "Ng'ang'a", picture: "/media/images/users/default-user.png"}
description: "gsgsgsgsgsergegreherhrehr fnfjrtjrtjrjrjrjrjrj"
freelancer: {id: "ddc249f1-69c5-4418-85c9-4e0131724fb2", firstName: "Dan", lastName: "Ng'ang'a", picture: "/media/images/users/default-user.png"}
id: "10a6a311-a68c-47b0-97fc-013bf5da3375"
location: "Ruiru"
postedOn: "5/11/2019 3:13:41 AM"
price: 600
rating: 0
schedule: "5/11/2019 9:00:00 AM"
skills: (2) [{…}, {…}]
status: 0
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Skills is an array , try this console.log(this.skills[0]['name']); this will print only first skill name in that array

Comment: thenks for the response but im only getting one result name. Im getting plumber alone and i need to get all skills. how do i do that?